# arraylists of longitude and latitude pass them in php and insert them to mysql,how?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I have two arraylists (longitude elements and latitude elements) which I want to pass them in the php script and then in mysql(wamp).

```
for (int i = 0; i < Latitude_mysql.size(); i++)
{
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Latitude_mysql",Latitude_mysql.get(i)));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Longitude_mysql",Longitude_mysql.get(i)));
}//by this way I send them in php script,but I m not sure if it is the appropriate
```

in the php I am writing something like this but I don t know how to continue:

```
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO route(latitude,longitude,trek_id_r)
    values (?, ? , ? )"))
    {
    /* Set our params */

   $lati[] = $_POST['Latitude_mysql[]'];
   $longi[] = $_POST['Longitude_mysql[]'];
```

and then???

I need the latitude and longitude to be inserted respectively, i.e: if the values are:

```
Longitude_mysql: 30.24 , 50.24
Latitude_mysql: 23.43 , 24.56
trek_id_r= 2
```

in mysql in table `route` I need this result:

```
Longitude | Latitude | Trek_id_r
30,24     | 23,43    | 2
50,24     | 24,56    | 2
```

I have read about converting the arraylists to json or implode and multiple mysqli insert so something relevant would be useful and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate the coord list and insert each in mysql. You will have two inserts in this case